# Alternative for new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContextHelper.Current).Application in net6.0-windows | Porting from .NET Framework 4.8

Tags: .net-6.0, .net-4.8

I am porting my class library from .NET 4.8 to net6.0-windows.
What is the alternative for `new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContextHelper.Current).Application`?

```
                Culture = systemParamUtility.GetSystemParameter(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContextHelper.Current).Application,
                    SystemParameterConstants.DateTimeDisplayCulture) ?? _defaultCulture;
```